# Permission for group of users that allows visit only one page

Tags: django, django-permissions

The issue that I have a group named `Driver`, and I want that users of that group to be able to visit only one special page with the url `'/driver/'` and no others. How do I implement such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Django's permission system to create any permission you want and then use the [permission_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) to enforce your new permission.  Or you could use the [user_passess_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) decorator to check if they're in the group and reject them from disallowed urls.

You could also create a middleware that checks if the user is in the Driver group and returns a HttpResponseForbidden if they request a disallowed url, but middlewares can slow down every request to your app.  You should be wary of doing too much there.